# Magento - Overriding block template in two modules

Tags: php, magento

I have one module that is setting the order history block like this:

```
  <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_tab_info">
         <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_history" name="order_history" template="sales/order/view/history.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

But I'm writing a new module that I want to use a different history.phtml file.  In my module's layout.xml I've written:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_history">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mymodule/sales/order/view/history.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

But unfortunately this still doesn't work for me.  Please advise where I'm going wrong?

I've tried to make my module depend on this other module in app/etc/modules but that's not fixed it for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't added my layout.xml into my config.xml.